# Voltage and amperage requirements for resistance heating of glass

Tags: voltage, resistance, amperage, thyristor, electrode

I am planning to introduce electric heating/boosting in my glass melting furnace.
The present temperature of the glass is around 1200 deg C and I need to raise it up to 1300 deg C. I am trying to get the design for a scott transformer of 10kVA, thyristor control panel for the job. 2 molybednum electrodes will be inserted into the hot glass and the control panel will supply the electrodes with the required voltage and amperage for heating of glass to the required temperature. I understand that the resistivity of glass starts falling with the rise in glass temperature and since the resistivity of molten glass is low, it might need low voltage and high amperage at the electrodes to heat up the glass.
The total glass pull/production is 100 kgs per hour.

My question is : 
1. Can anyone help me in deciding the  voltage range and amperage range required for efficient heating of the glass from 1200 - 1300 deg C?
2. Will the distance between the electrodes have an effect on the efficiency of heating?

Comment: Q=mCp(T2-T1) plus losses... once you have that then you can decide V & A...

Comment: All we really need to know is what resistance the glass will have at various temperatures. If you can post a resource for this, we can probably provide an answer.

Comment: hi drew and solar mike,
many thanks for your response. I am not an electrical engineer so it is difficult for me to under what mike has written (Q = mCp(T2-t1).
I will try to find out the resistance of glass in the range of 1200 - 1300 deg C

Comment: Q is the energy, m is the mass to be heated, Cp is the amount of heat per unit mass, T2-T1 is the temperature rise.

Comment: Thanks mike. We know that the energy requirement may be in the range of 6 - 8 kVA. Hence we are designing for 10 kVA. What we dont know if what is the ideal ratio between volts and the amps (at 10 kVA) to get maximum effective heating.

Comment: Hello Drew,
It took might some time to search about the glass resistivity.
It seems that glass resistivity is 4600 ohm*m at 1000 deg C and 800 Ohm*m at 1500 deg C. So I assume that between a temperature of 1200 - 1300 deg C, the resisitivity should be between 2500 - 1500 ohms*m